# tensorflow can we subclass layers such as Conv2D or Dense?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I know that it is possible to create customize layer in tensorflow 2 like this:

```
class CustomDense(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self,unit,activation):
        super(CustomDense, self).__init__(name='my_layer')
        self.unit=unit
        self.activation=activation

    def build(self, input_shape):

        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[1],self.unit),trainable=Truename='kernel')
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.unit,),name='bias')


    def call(self,inputs):
        x=tf.matmul(inputs,self.kernel) + self.bias
        output=self.activation(x)
        return output
```

But is it possible to create a custom layer which its parent's class is an existing layer like Dense or Conv2D?

```
class CustomDense(tf.keras.layers.Dense):
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue, but I haven't yet found an answer